# PHP Contact Form isn't working & the form isn't coming out correctly

Tags: php, forms, email

```
    <div class="row" id="box2" >
<div class="col-xs-12 center-block text-center">
    <h1>Get In Touch</h1><br>
    <?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

 ?>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="role" method="post" name="contactform" action="<?php echo $self; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cusname" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cusemail"id="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                </div>
        </div><div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-center">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['cusname'];
        $email = $_POST['cusemail'];
        $subject = $_POST['cussubject'];
        $reason = $_POST['cusmessage']
        $emailto = "alantessier97@gmail.com";
        $sub = "Filled in form from website"


        $header = "From = $name <$email>\r\nReply-To: $email\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME.Verson 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

        $message = "From : $name, Email : $email<br /><hr />$reason";

        mail($emailto, $sub, $message, $header);

        echo "Thank you for contacting us.";
 }
 ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

MY code isn't acting correctly the php keeps acting up.  I truthfully, dont know any php and i found this code online. I've tried a bunch of codes but none seem to work and im tired of searching. So if anyone could help me get this one to work, that would be great! For instance the php code comes up on my contact page and it doesn't submit like it should. I would appreciate some help here.  So if I'm missing something here, i Would appreciate some assistance.

Also if there is something wrong with my html feel free to fix that as well.  But mainly i'm looking for help on my php.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you see the PHP code when you load the page, it could be because your web server doesn't know how to parse PHP code.

Do you have a web server? Do you have other PHP code that works? Remember that browsers cannot run PHP code and you need to install something like [Apache](https://www.apache.org/) to interpret your source code. If you are on Windows, you can just download and install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/). If you're on Linux, install the `Apache2` or `httpd` packages, along with `php`.

Comment: I have other php code that works & I have a server.